# IBM Watson Assistant - use second Intent

Tags: ibm-watson

please help :-)

I use syntax intents.confidence > 0.95 for answer first. And quest is:

If confidence is NOT greater than 0.95, I need use second intent.

It!s possible please?

Thanks for help.

V.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like

```
intents[0].confidence < 0.95 and intents[1].confidence > 0.5
```

Comment: It's not working - I need if not true this : intents[0].confidence < 0.95 --> use round for second intent.